# Play sound.mp3 with node-sonos-http-api

Tags: api, sonos

I have a MP3 file: myMusic.mp3, in 192.168.1.196/myPubcli/myMusicFolder/myMusic.mp3
With [enter link description here](https://github.com/jishi/node-sonos-http-api) I want to play this file but I can't how.
I try http:\localhost:5005\myRoom\tunein\play\44491 with success! :-)
But how I can play that MP3 file?